# How can I get child value with if & else condition (Firebase,SDK)

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I am having trouble with my codes. What I want to do in my Login page is log as admin using email/password and when "role" is equal to admin (the other role is Guest). The admin page is MainActivity.class and the Guest page is Home.class. Can someone help me :)

[image]

And here is my code:

```
    private void onAuthSuccess(FirebaseUser user) {
    DatabaseReference ref = 
    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                String role = ds.getKey();

                DatabaseReference userKeyDatabase =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");
                ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot == null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "****NULLL****", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else if(dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue().equals("Admin")) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }else{
                startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, Home.class));
                finish();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };

        userKeyDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }}
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
       ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
    }
```

I am not sure about my code as well :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `check role of users` login you can do something like this

```
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                DatabaseReference db=firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("users");

     db.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) 
                                        if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                                            Log.d("user exits","usere hai");
                                           String value =dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue().toString();

                                           if(value.equals("Admin") && value != null){
 startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
                                        }else{
 startActivity(new Intent(SignInActivity.this, Home.class));
                finish();
                                        }

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) { }
                            });
```

Comment: Hi Sir thank you for this, however I still got an error from this statement .equalTo(email)   = "Cannot resolve symbol 'email'

Comment: Declare variable **email** and store value in it, then try to pass in that statement .

Comment: Do you mean to put a specific value on it? ex. 
String email = "test@gmail.com"?

Comment: I tried this String email = "email", no more error but when I pressed the sign in button, nothing happens

Comment: Because that email doesnt exist in your firebase , try putting email which exists in your database

Comment: Still not working sir, I put an existing email as a value ex. String email ="test@gmail.com" and the app keeps on forclosing

Comment: Post your logcat also

Comment: For somehow my last post was deleted, anyway the error still occurs even putting the one you told me. :(

Comment: problem is not in this code,, in your logcat it  was on line 209 check what is there .or post another question